# Spellcheck does not work for uppercase words in TinyMCE for IE10

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE (version 3.5.10) to provide editing functionality to my application and inside tinyMCE init method, I call browser's spellcheck engine as follows;

```
    tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
          ed.getBody().setAttribute('spellcheck', true);
      });
   }
   });
```

However, this work well in IE10 for lower case letters. however spellcheck functionality does not work for upper case words. This funcationality work well on chrome browser for both lower and upper case words. Any idea why this does not work for upper case words?

Comment: Microsoft introduced spell check functionality to the Internet Explorer with IE10. However spell check functionality only work for lower case words (and word start with capital letter) in IE10 and later browsers, it fails for upper case words (all cap words), even it does not underline for all caps misspell words. 

http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/SpellChecking/ 

Following links further confirms that spell check engine use in MS Word too fail on this; 
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/spell-check-doesnt-work-uppercase-words-microsoft-word-75888.html

Comment: As per the below link, IE's Spell check engine does not support pre existing texts. 

http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/SpellChecking/ 

"Preexisting text will not be spellchecked, however pasted text will be checked when it is inserted."

Comment: However, I could not find any documentation of this from Microsoft officially, or any other confirmation of this limitation...